# I am getting problem in send data like name and email to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This coding is at PhoneAuth.clas then I am giving to mobile authentication to PhoneAuthOtp.class -  meanwhile i am passing data like nameInput and emailInput to AccountActivity.class but data is not passing. I have done coding at AccountActivity.class at all.

```
findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String emailInput = etemaill.getText().toString();

                String number = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                String nameInput = etnamee.getText().toString();



                Intent in = new Intent(PhoneAuth.this, PhoneAuthOtp.class);
                in.putExtra("datanam",nameInput);
                in.putExtra("dataem",emailInput);



                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etnamee.getText())) {
                    etnamee.setError("Enter Your Name");
                    etnamee.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (emailInput.isEmpty()) {
                    etemaill.setError("Enter Your Email");
                    return;
                } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()) {
                    etemaill.setError("Enter Your Valid Email");
                    return;
                }


                if (number.isEmpty() || number.length() < 10) {
                    editText.setError("Valid number is required");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                String phoneNumber = "+91" + number;

                Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneAuth.this, PhoneAuthOtp.class);
                intent.putExtra("phonenumber", phoneNumber);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You are initialized Intent twice. (`Intent in = new Intent(PhoneAuth.this, PhoneAuthOtp.class);`). Once is enough.

Answer (score 0):

**You are initialized Intent twice. please try this code and check**

```
   findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String emailInput = etemaill.getText().toString();
            String number = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            String nameInput = etnamee.getText().toString();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etnamee.getText())) {
                etnamee.setError("Enter Your Name");
                etnamee.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (emailInput.isEmpty()) {
                etemaill.setError("Enter Your Email");
                return;
            } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()) {
                etemaill.setError("Enter Your Valid Email");
                return;
            }


            if (number.isEmpty() || number.length() < 10) {
                editText.setError("Valid number is required");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            String phoneNumber = "+91" + number;

            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneAuth.this, PhoneAuthOtp.class);
            intent.putExtra("phonenumber", phoneNumber);
            intent.putExtra("datanam",nameInput);
            intent.putExtra("dataem",emailInput);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I checked, this is working only when I changed PhoneAuthOtp.class to AccountActivity.class and give without mobile authentication. Now What should I Do?

Comment: phoneNumber, name, and email  this data pass in  PhoneAuth to PhoneAuthOtp.

PhoneAuthOtp  activity get data in a bundle through